# How to use value of model as a name of other model in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var myApp = angular.module('LoginApp',[]);

myApp.controller('dynamic', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.a_1= "Admin";

   $scope.auction_no = 1;

   $scope.item = [{ A:"a" , B:1 }];
}]);
```

I have to give model name in HTML in {{ x }} , x should be {{item.A}}_{{auction_no}} like this . and finally it should give output Admin

Comment: Can you please add an example as exactly what do you want to extract?

Comment: Your question is not very clear can you please explain a little more.

Comment: Create a service that acts as a go-between for your controllers. Inject this service into both of them, and modify as necessary. One solution would be to use `$q` to create a promise that you never resolve but watch for updates, and use that as the cue to update your models.

Comment: Sorry....  I had edited the ques.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bracket accessor `$scope[$scope.item[0].A + "_" + $scope.auction_no]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make your first variable an object:

```
$scope.auctions = {
  a_1: 'Admin'
};

$scope.auction_no = 1;
$scope.item = [{ A:"a" , B:1 }];

var x = $scope.auctions[$scope.item[0]['A'] + '_' + $scope.auction_no];
```

The variable `x` should hold the value `Admin` at this point.